# In the opening sequence of the walking dead, what are the crows feasting on?

Tags: the-walking-dead

I've watched the opening of The Walking Dead countless times, but I can't identify the white-ish animal the crows are eating on the road. My fiancé and I jokingly call it the rabbit/cat/teddy bear.

Comment: The site isn't supported by the show so I wouldn't submit as an answer, but seriable.com stated it was a rabbit when they were reviewing the intro sequence before the show came out.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure it's a cat. You can't be 100% sure based on the direction of the shot. The animal appears at 0:23 in the [opening](http://vimeo.com/29180214). I judged cat based on the length of the leg, the tail and fur. but it could be a small dog. It is definitely not a rodent of any kind since the head shape is wrong for it.

Comment: Looks like a case of rigor *Morris* to me as well.

Answer (score 3):

It's the teddy bear that was in the beginning of the first episode of Season 1. It was foreshadowing. Matter of fact, the little girl that Rick had to shoot was carrying a teddy bear.

Comment: Good first answer, though you may want to provide supporting evidence. If you can find some, edit it into your answer. Even though it's an old question by now, the QA may still accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a juvenile cat - it has the foot pads of a cat, as well as the hind leg joints and ears of a cat. It does not have the anatomy of a teddy bear, but it does read a little bit like a teddy bear. I believe this is because it is not a real animal, but a stuffed toy made to look like a cat and filled with something that the crows would want to eat. This would be in keeping with industry regulations for the humane treatment of animals in filming.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the same unharmed teddy bear in the previous clips. Possible foreshadowing. Or it could just be a really fuzzy animal. Cat or some kind of roadkill?